Lombok annotations are no processed by Maven but visible correct in IDE
I've added Lombok to a Java project.
Now I see multiple Lombok annotation related errors while I'm running Maven mvn clean install  or mvn spring-boot:run. For example for logging
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable log

Despite that, everything looks great in my IDE. All Lombok related stuff doesn't show any errors.
I've already checked everything regarding configuring. Lombok must work.
And it really works with other projects.
What could be the reason?

Ah, this is a rare case that I've got.
Someone added the <annotationProcessors> section to the project's pom.xml.
In this case Maven defines the annotation processors directly by class name, instead of paths.
Using this section means Maven will run only the specified processors and ignore all others, including Lombok, unless you explicitly include it.
Why Lombok Fails with <annotationProcessors>
When you add the <annotationProcessors> section, you override the default behavior where Maven automatically discovers annotation processors.
Lombok isn't invoked unless its processor is explicitly listed.
Solution 1.1
The solution will be looking like this
<annotationProcessorPaths>
    <path>
        <!-- ... your custom annotation -->
    </path>
    <path>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    </path>
</annotationProcessorPaths>
<annotationProcessors>
    <!-- ... some your custom processor or annotationProcessor sections ... -->

    <!-- Lombok's annotation processor section. -->. 
    <processor>lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor</processor>
</annotationProcessors>

Solution 1.2
Additionally, Unit-tests run within a single file in JetBrains IDEA continued to crash with the same unprocessed Lombok annotations errors.
I fixed it by manually updating Annotation Processors settings section.
Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Annotation Processors
by adding there lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor.


Only Maven dependency addition in the pom.xml will not help you.
You need to install lombok in your system, where your eclipse is there.
Then those compilation issue will resolve.

It often happens when you add lombok from spring boot starters i.e. spring initializer or with Intelij Idea IDE. Actually it gives nothing wrong but configures something which is not needed in most of the times and most of the IDEs are failed to uderstand this. For example it adds optional field
<optional>true</optional>

In plugins scope it adds this
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

Which is not required. It also configures annotation processors path which is not required for most of the IDEs like intelij idea.
To overcome this issue remove all these and use only which lombok's maven repository provides
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok
for example
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.36</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

